# vert-x 3.3.2 http client exception handler

Tags: javascript, java, exception, vert.x, asynchttpclient

Am using Vert-x 3.3.2.

HttpClient.exceptionHandler and HttpClientRequest.exceptionHandler is throwing compilation error.

Whether exception handler is removed for this classes.

Any other way to handle this.

```
    var client = vertx.createHttpClient(options);
    var request = client.getNow(8080, "localhost", data, function (resp)  {

            resp.bodyHandler(function (body) {
                console.log(body.toString());
            });
            resp.exceptionHandler(function(err){
                console.log("Response Exception:::"+err.getCode());
            });

    });
    request.exceptionHandler(function(Err){
        console.log("Client Exception ::: "+Err);
    });
```

Also tried

```
    client.exceptionHandler(function(Err){
        console.log("Client Exception ::: "+Err);
    });
```

Could anyone help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using getNow() method.
xxxNow() methods don't receive exceptionHandler:
http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/js/#_making_requests

> IMPORTANT XXXNow methods cannot receive an exception handler.

Comment: Thanks Soshin for  your reply. Then how to catch the exception here.

Comment: **Thanks** soshin.. This actually solved my problem. Thank you so much.